# splitting a file into multiple files based on size and occurrence

Tags: linux, file, split

I have a big txt file (~ 1GB) that contains specific text.

example of the file content:

is there a way in linux to split this file into multiple files based on size and occurrence at the same time ?

so for example, I want to split my file into files of 100 MBs , but where each file must begin with specific character , and the last line of the file that precede it must be the line that precede that character in the original file.
noting that this character exist frequently in the original file , so the size of the split files will match.

Edit : you can download the txt file from here :[Sample File][2]

Comment: use split command ... but that will not meet your condition regarding the lines

Comment: you have that input as text ?

Comment: @user2413548 I added it as text in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp needs a little tuning, since the resultfiles do not match completely. Run it as: perl  scriptname.pl < sample.txt and you get chunk files.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use IO::File;


my $all = join('', (<STDIN>));

my (@pieces) = ($all =~ m%([IZO]\(.*?\)\{.*?\r\n\}\r\n)%gsx);

my $n = 1;
my $FH;
foreach my $P (@pieces) {
   if ($P =~ m%^I%) {
      undef $FH;
      $FH = IO::File->new(sprintf("> chunk%d", $n));
      $n++;
   }
   print $FH $P;
}
```

Less memory hungry:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def split(filename, size=100, outputPrefix="xxx"):
    with open(filename) as I:
        n = 0
        FNM = "{}{}.txt"
        O = open(FNM.format(outputPrefix, n), "w")
        toWrite = size*1024*1024
        for line in I:
            toWrite -= len(line)
            if line[0] == 'I' and toWrite < 0:
                O.close()
                toWrite = size*1024*1024
                n += 1
                O = open(FNM.format(outputPrefix, n), "w")
            O.write(line)
        O.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    split(sys.argv[1])
```

use: python scriptname.py sample.txt
all concatenated files are equale to sample.txt

Comment: NOTE: the perl code will consume memory for your full inputfile *2 I guess

Comment: this script split the file only by occurrence of "I(" , so if it exists n times , n chunks will be generated.
What I need is to generate less files based on size.

Comment: size parameter added:  size in Mb, parameter is optional and defaults to 100

Comment: I'm getting the following error when running the second script :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file_split.py", line 21, in <module>
    split(sys.argv[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: you need to pass the file as an argument: so, python scriptname.py yourfile

Comment: thank you for the above . it's working now.
What if I want to result files to be .txt ?